# Как переписать условие с помощью лямбда функций

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс Valera c определенными полями. Так же есть класс Actions c действиями над этими полями. Есть метод меняющий метод Happiness:

```
if (valera.Happiness > -10)
  {
    valera.Happiness = -10;
  } 
 valera.Happiness += (int)actions.SelectToken("goToWork")?.SelectToken("happiness");
```

Можно ли как нибудь с помощью лямбда функций сократить данное условие и присваивание? Потому что в будущем таких проверок будет множество и не хотелось бы загромождать код

Comment: Оно не компилируется, или что? Что с этим кодом не так? `метод меняющий метод Happiness` - ничего не понял.

Comment: Код компилируется, хотел узнать можно ли с записать это через лямбда функции, дабы сократить выражения

Comment: `valera.Happiness = Math.Min(valera.Happiness, -10) + (int)actions.SelectToken("goToWork")?.SelectToken("happiness")`?

Comment: @VladD, ответы - в ответы. Впрочем, каст из `?.` в int всё равно сомнительный...

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда в конец добавить `?? 0`;

Comment: @Qwertiy: ну, чисто формально у меня никаких лямбд, поэтому я не вполне уверен, что это покатит за ответ.

Comment: @VladD, если тащить минимум из linq, то можно с лямбдой.

Comment: @Qwertiy для Linq нужна коллекция. Создавать коллекцию из 2 значений только ради того чтобы вызвать для нее `.Min()` - плохая практика во всех случаях, в первую очередь из-за неэффективности подхода. Скорее всего автор хотел тернарный оператор `?:`, но некорректно выразился, я полагаю.